# Compilation user created command not working properly on texmaker

Tags: texmaker

I'm compiling an APA7 document on Texmaker using Biber as a backend for bibliography management. The document needs to be compiled in four steps: PDFLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTex+PDFLaTex. When I compile each step at a time, the document properly compiles. Then, I created a user command to compile in one step, but the command is not working properly: when I click on the command the first time, index and table of contents do not appear on the PDF. By clicking a second time the missing items are included in the PDF, but citations remain missing. Can you explain me first, why I need to click twice on the command to get the full document content, and second, why I'm not getting a full compilation and citations remain missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: are you sure you only need one pdflatex run after bibtex? that seems unlikely

Comment: When I compile one step at a time, I only need one pdflatex after bibtex. Anyhow, I added a second pdflatex after bibtex to my user command and the error of not getting the citation remains.

Comment: after biber or bibtex the bibliography is generated so latex can input that but usually that is towards the end of the document, so any foward reference \cite need another run. really you should run makeindex _after_ that as the cite may have changed page breaking ,  then pdflatex again to pick up the index. So it would be very surprising if `PDFLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTex+PDFLaTex` worked from a clean project. also you say in the text you use biber, but your pipeline uses bibtex, which would also explain  why citations not resolved

Comment: As I mentioned before and following your logic, I changed my command adding an additional pdflatex, so my new command is PDFLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTex+PDFLaTex+PDFLaTex and I'm still not getting the citations. When I compile using the four first steps one step at a time, I get the citations. What I don't understand is why I get the error running the user command and not running the steps individually.

Comment: Do you need biber or bibtex? These are two different programs!

Comment: For APA7 you need biblatex using biber as a backend, so when you are compiling in textmaker you need to configure it using biber %. I'm not having a problem compiling my document as long as I do it one step at a time using the following four-steps sequence: PDFLaTex+MakeIndex+BibTex+PDFLaTex, but when I use a user command with this sequence to compile in one step, I'm not getting the citations.